# How to limit Android edit text field only for some selected characters

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to limit users allowed to type only some selected character set (Eg: A or B or C or D) in Android layout.xml

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`digits`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adigits) attribute, only the characters passed to `digits` will be allowed in the EditText.

```
android:digits="abc123"
```

And yes, "digits" is a misleading name, it accepts letters and symbols too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `inputType` attribute:

```
   <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text_id"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="number" />
```

Possible Values for `android:inputType` attribute in edit text are: `none, text, textCapCharacters, textCapWords, textCapSentences, textAutoCorrect, textAutoComplete, textMultiLine, textImeMultiLine, textNoSuggestions, textUri, textEmailAddress, textEmailSubject, textShortMessage, textLongMessage, textPersonName, textPostalAddress, textPassword, textVisiblePassword, textWebEditText, textFilter, textPhonetic, textWebEmailAddress, textWebPassword, number, numberSigned, numberDecimal, numberPassword, phone, datetime, date, time`

Comment: Which one of these limits the input to "A", "B", "C", or "D" only? (Since I've addressed you a few times today: I'm _not_ trying to harass you. I feel that some of your actions have been incorrect or incomplete. So I am asking legitimate questions to clarify the matter.)

Answer (score 0):

This `android:digit` will allow only the digits and alphabets you want to be filled in EditText.

```
<EditText 
      android:inputType="text" 
      android:digits="0123456789*qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,_,-" 
      android:hint="Only letters, digits, _ and - allowed"
    />
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, this gets flagged as low quality.

Comment: you'd better explain why he has to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can set your EditText Field like this...

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="THE SELECTED CHARACTERS THAT USERS ARE ALLOWED TO TYPE" 
/>
```

By listing the selected characters (A,B,C,and D) that users are allowed to type in the android:digits, you are limiting the possible characters that users can type. This is the easiest way I've learned through searching.