# Remove a key from android keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

i need to remove a key from a standard keyboard and add new one instead of it with the functionality of newly added one.

Basically using this functionality for edittext.

```
 <EditText android:text="@+id/EditText01" android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="phone" android:digits="1234567890,"></EditText>
```

Please find required functionality in the image.can we do this?[image]

instead of X#( i need only comma and is functionality

Comment: Just read this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433077/how-to-limit-android-edit-text-field-only-for-some-selected-characters/13433506#13433506

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to find the source code for the default input method editor, download it, create your own input method editor that has this replacement, ship your revised input method editor (in your app or in another app), and ask your users to switch to your input method editor. I project that 99% of your users will ignore you.

Otherwise, you have no control over the keys shown on an input method editor. Some input method editors do not have *any* keys (e.g., Graffiti using gestures). You can use `android:inputType` and related attributes as hints, but not all input method editors will honor them and they do not offer per-key flexibility.